# How to convert str "6\u2009000" to int()

Tags: python, unicode

I have a str with the format '6\u2009000'.
How do I transform it into an int?

If I use `a = int(str, 10)`, I get:

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6\u2009000'
```

Comment: \u2009 is a Unicode sequence. What output were you hoping to see?

Comment: U+2009 is the Unicode character "THIN SPACE". `\u2009` is the Python/JSON representation of such a character. Suggest you strip whitespace from your string before trying to process it as a number

Comment: btw don't use `str` as a variable name, it is a built-in function

Comment: `int(str, 10)` reads a based `10` number from a string. so `int("12", 3)` returns `5`. Since `12` based `3` is `5`.

Comment: @MSH yes and how does that help?

Comment: @Matiiss There is illigan characters in `6\u2009000` for a base `10`  number. I mean seems like OP misunderstood the functions behavior.

Comment: @BrutusForcus I want to get int a = 6000

Comment: You have to remove the `\u2009` character, or replace it with an underscore. `int` is limited in the forms it recognizes.

Comment: Note: maybe it is a locale thing, so https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.delocalize may help. It is difficult to generalize all cases, so maybe you should just detect and manually insert new rules.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of latest comments, this is what you could do:

```
print(int('6\u2009000'.replace('\u2009', '_')))
```

or just:

```
print(int('6\u2009000'.replace('\u2009', '')))
```

The latter form is more reliable because it does not depend on where the Unicode character is positioned

Comment: or `print(int(''.join('6\u2009000'.split())))`

Comment: @Matiiss That certainly works for this example